# custom file input button, creating an invisible input file type inside div inside button for file input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, tailwind-css

I would like to make a file input button like the one in Amazon write a review pictured below

[image: amazon upload button]

How is it possible that the entire button opens up the file dialog on click if the input file type is hidden?

[image: amazon upload photo button code]

My code here hides the input file type button but does not open the file dialog. It is using React with tailwind classes

```
    <button
      type="button"
      className="p-6"
    >
      <div aria-label="Add a photo">
        <HiOutlinePlus className="text-4xl" />
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" className="hidden" />
      </div>
    </button>
```

Comment: You can use ref to get reference of the input, and then when the add button is clicked, click the input with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How is it possible that the entire button opens up the file dialog on click if the input file type is hidden?

The probably use a separate widget that then opens the hidden file input on click, as follows:

```js
function openFileUpload() {
  document.getElementById("hiddenFile").click();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openFileUpload()" type="button">Visible Button</button>
<input type="file" id="hiddenFile" style="visibility:hidden">
```